# db2move importing data in tables with foreign key constraint

Tags: database, db2

How to handle the foreign key constraint issue while using db2look, db2move to backup and restore database ?
The DDLs(genereated using db2look) creates constraints while restoring the database and hence the data error happens during importing data using db2move.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options for populating an empty DB2 database that has RI constraints:

- Examine all the FK dependencies in your database and change the order of your `IMPORT` statements accordingly to prevent momentary violations of your RI constraints. This may not be an option for tables with self-referencing foreign keys.
- Instead of populating the tables via `IMPORT`, use the [LOAD](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-load) utility, which ignores table constraints. LOAD will put any target tables with constraints (and their dependent tables downstream) into CHECK PENDING status, which will prevent write access. Once all the tables are loaded, use the [SET INTEGRITY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-set-integrity) command on those tables to verify that they satisfy all of their constraints.
- Relocate the `ALTER TABLE` statements in your DDL to a separate script that gets run only after all of the tables have been populated.

Comment: while running SET INTEGRITY command, table dependencies needs to be considered ? I have got cyclic dependency, how to proceed in such scenario ?

Comment: I guess i found it "set integrity for employee, department immediate checked"

Comment: Trying to run 'db2move database Load -l backuploc -u user -p pass' but getting following error : 'SQLCODE:  -3126  -  SQLSTATE:
SQL3126N  Remote client requires absolute path for files and directories.'

Comment: Is there only one db2 command that does ddl and data copy in one step? I think the documentation of db2move is misleading https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html

I'm sure that most people who use it, think that db2move does the complete copy (of a schema for example). But no. You have to issue thousands of commands and options and notice that it wasn't that you wanted at the end...
Really, who wants just thousands of tables with data but without references after db2move import... Disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

1. First disable constraints and then execute db2move import.
2. After imported data into tables , re-enable constraints

ALTER TABLE  ALTER FOREIGN KEY  NOT ENFORCED

and then to re-enable:

ALTER TABLE  ALTER FOREIGN KEY  ENFORCED

Thanks,
Naidu

Answer (score 0):

Its better to execute the table defenition and fk constraint defenition in different process.
To avoid integrity check when you load the data using db2move tools, the fk defenition must be executed later after you do the import/load process.

After you run the db2look to dump the ddl of your database. Just separate the foreign key constraint to the separate file. Better be if the other object like triggers, sp, or views on different file too. So, right after you load the data, execute the fk constarint, triggers, sp, and views.

Good luck.